# Android DownloadManager java.lang.SecurityException: Unsupported path

Tags: android, android-download-manager

My application works fine until I got the following error message recently:

> java.lang.SecurityException: Unsupported path /storage/emulated/0/xxxzip/1234/abcde.zip

My permission in manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And I also request run-time permission:

```
    public  boolean isStoragePermissionGranted() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{ android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
            return true;
        }
    }

The app crashes at the last line of this code:

        Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);
        String downloadDir = savePath+"/zip/"+productId; 
        File direct = new File(downloadDir);
        if(!direct.exists())
        {
            if(direct.mkdirs())
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"folder "+direct+" created");
            }
        }

        int fileNamePos = url.lastIndexOf("/");
        String fileName = url.substring(fileNamePos+1);
        request.setDestinationUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadDir + "/" + fileName)));

        final long download_id = m_downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

It was working previously and it's also working in simulator. Any idea?

By the way, here is the example of my download path: `/storage/emulated/0/MyAppName/zip/1234`. **If I save to another folder like `Downloads`, it will be ok. So I think it's definitely the permission issue.**

Comment: `String downloadDir = savePath+"/zip/"+productId` You did not define savePath. Please start your code with it. Nobody knows what you do. Also tell Android version of used Android device.

Comment: If mkdir fails you still continue with the code. No good. `if(!direct.mkdirs()) return;`

Comment: Dont let your app crash and catch that exception.

Comment: @blackapps Actually the savePath is defined but not in the code I presented. And the problem is not in `direct.mkdirs()` because I debugged and found the folder is created.